# Is there a list of language's google webfont subsets requirement?

Tags: localization, subset, google-font-api

For example:

Turkish language (**tr_TR**) needs **latin-ext** subset.

Is there a list for which language needs which subsets for google webfonts?

Answer (score 1):

Google has not publicly documented this, but it is realistic assumption that by “Latin (latin)” they mean Latin 1, more exactly the windows-1252 character repertoire (= ISO Latin 1, aka. ISO 8859-1, with some punctuation marks added).

Any Latin letters beyond that are “Latin Extended (latin-ext)”, if available at all – most Google font do not cover *all* Latin letters.

Windows-1252 and ISO 8859-1 were designed to cover (most characters in) Western and Northern European languages. For details see [Coverage of European languages by ISO Latin alphabets](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/8859.html). Windows-1252 *may* be sufficient for a non-European language written in Latin letters (e.g., Indonesian), but that’s coincidental.